# Get multiple level of one to many relationship results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph that looks like this

```
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
  \  /    \  |  /
   S1        S2
      \    /
        E1
```

There can be many E nodes. But the essence from the above is:
It is a one to many mapping between E and S nodes
It is a one to many mapping between S and A nodes
The same S1 can also point to another E node, but I want to extract the following relationship:

For each E node, get all the S nodes and for each S node we get, get all the A nodes.

I know for just E and S, I can do:

```
match (e:E)<--(s:S)
return e, collect(distinct s)
```

But I am not sure how to do this with two level of such mapping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the following stub data to represent your graph

```
CREATE (e1:E {id: 'e1'})
CREATE (e2:E {id: 'e2'})
CREATE (s1:S {id: 's1'})
CREATE (s2:S {id: 's2'})
CREATE (a1:A {id: 'a1'})
CREATE (a2:A {id: 'a2'})
CREATE (a3:A {id: 'a3'})
CREATE (a4:A {id: 'a4'})
CREATE (a5:A {id: 'a5'})
CREATE (e1)-[:TO]->(s1)
CREATE (e1)-[:TO]->(s2)
CREATE (s1)-[:TO]->(a1)
CREATE (s1)-[:TO]->(a2)
CREATE (s2)-[:TO]->(a3)
CREATE (s2)-[:TO]->(a4)
CREATE (s2)-[:TO]->(a5)
CREATE (e2)-[:TO]->(s2)
```

[image]

You can retrieve **paths** from E to A simply by aliasing the full pattern

```
MATCH path=(e:E)-->(:S)-->(:A)
RETURN path
```

This will give you a full path, note that a path is a sequenced list of relationships having a start and end node

Graph result

[image]

Tabular result

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"path"                                                 │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"id":"e1"},{},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"s2"},{},{"id":"a4"}]│
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"id":"e1"},{},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"s2"},{},{"id":"a5"}]│
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"id":"e1"},{},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"s2"},{},{"id":"a3"}]│
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"id":"e1"},{},{"id":"s1"},{"id":"s1"},{},{"id":"a1"}]│
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"id":"e1"},{},{"id":"s1"},{"id":"s1"},{},{"id":"a2"}]│
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"id":"e2"},{},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"s2"},{},{"id":"a4"}]│
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"id":"e2"},{},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"s2"},{},{"id":"a5"}]│
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"id":"e2"},{},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"s2"},{},{"id":"a3"}]│
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

To maybe make it more clear, let's limit the result to only one path

```
MATCH path=(e:E)-->(:S)-->(:A)
RETURN path
LIMIT 1
```

[image]

Tabular result

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"path"                                                 │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"id":"e1"},{},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"s2"},{},{"id":"a4"}]│
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

You can now collect paths per `E` node

```
MATCH path=(e:E)-->(:S)-->(:A)
RETURN e, collect(path) AS paths
```

The graph result would be similar since it returns all nodes and rels, but the tabular result shows now the aggregation

```
╒═══════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"e"        │"paths"                                                               │
╞═══════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"id":"e1"}│[[{"id":"e1"},{},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"s2"},{},{"id":"a4"}],[{"id":"e1"},│
│           │{},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"s2"},{},{"id":"a5"}],[{"id":"e1"},{},{"id":"s2"}│
│           │,{"id":"s2"},{},{"id":"a3"}],[{"id":"e1"},{},{"id":"s1"},{"id":"s1"},{│
│           │},{"id":"a1"}],[{"id":"e1"},{},{"id":"s1"},{"id":"s1"},{},{"id":"a2"}]│
│           │]                                                                     │
├───────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"id":"e2"}│[[{"id":"e2"},{},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"s2"},{},{"id":"a4"}],[{"id":"e2"},│
│           │{},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"s2"},{},{"id":"a5"}],[{"id":"e2"},{},{"id":"s2"}│
│           │,{"id":"s2"},{},{"id":"a3"}]]                                         │
└───────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

So far we returned full paths. You can extract nodes only from them using the `nodes()` function

```
MATCH path=(e:E)-->(:S)-->(:A)
RETURN nodes(path)
```

```
╒═════════════════════════════════════╕
│"nodes(path)"                        │
╞═════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"id":"e1"},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"a4"}]│
├─────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"id":"e1"},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"a5"}]│
├─────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"id":"e1"},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"a3"}]│
├─────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"id":"e1"},{"id":"s1"},{"id":"a1"}]│
├─────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"id":"e1"},{"id":"s1"},{"id":"a2"}]│
├─────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"id":"e2"},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"a4"}]│
├─────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"id":"e2"},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"a5"}]│
├─────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"id":"e2"},{"id":"s2"},{"id":"a3"}]│
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

And now, if you want to return a json tree like structure, you can use map projections

```
MATCH (e:E)
RETURN 
e {.*, s: [(e)-->(s:S) | s{.*, a: [(s)-->(a:A) | a{.*}]}]}
```

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"e"                                                                   │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"s":[{"a":[{"id":"a4"},{"id":"a5"},{"id":"a3"}],"id":"s2"},{"a":[{"id│
│":"a1"},{"id":"a2"}],"id":"s1"}],"id":"e1"}                           │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"s":[{"a":[{"id":"a4"},{"id":"a5"},{"id":"a3"}],"id":"s2"}],"id":"e2"│
│}                                                                     │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Let's format the first result a bit

```
{
    "s": [
        {
            "a": [
                {
                    "id": "a4"
                },
                {
                    "id": "a5"
                },
                {
                    "id": "a3"
                }
            ],
            "id": "s2"
        },
        {
            "a": [
                {
                    "id": "a1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "a2"
                }
            ],
            "id": "s1"
        }
    ],
    "id": "e1"
}
```

This sounds a bit cryptic but as soon as you understand how it works it is quite powerful, I suggest reading a bit more about it here :

- https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/maps/#cypher-map-projection
- https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-graphql-neo4j-3-1-preview/
- https://neo4j.com/developer-blog/a-comprehensive-guide-to-cypher-map-projection/
- 

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar issues in endogamous genealogy family trees. My experience might help you and others? Endogamy is typically describes as a person appearing more than once in the family tree (multiple Ahnentafels). But is it easier to analyze with graphs ... there are multiple paths to that common ancestor(s).

The graph has several enhancements. Paths are aliased and uniquely identifiable as you've described. The sequenced numbers in the path are used to create their ORDPATH which is a concatenated bitstring that sorts hierarchically. You can calculate the coefficient of relationship (COR) for between individuals and the coefficient of inbreeding if there is endogamy.

Creating a knowledge graph involves memorializing analytics in the graph as nodes, relationships or properties. This one-time activity makes downstream analytics faster and more intuitive (e.g., easier).

I'm now enhancing the graph further by creating path nodes with properties of the aliased path, start and end node identifiers. These nodes can be related to primary data making them supernodes. Using apoc.coll.intersection you can add an "intersect" relationship between paths.

The initial work on creating this KNOWLEDGE GRAPH is posted here:
https://www.wai.md/post/endogamy-i-the-knowledge-graph

The second effort should appear soon at the same blog.